# Mark user name in RecyclerView

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

Hello i need help in Mark user name in RecyclerView android 
i have try this but when scroll multiple name is marked.

```
  @Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MyViewHolder holder, int position) {


    List<User> users = this.userList;
    holder.tvUserName.setText(users.get(holder.getAdapterPosition()).getUserName());
    holder.tvPoints.setText(String.valueOf(users.get(holder.getAdapterPosition()).getPoint()));
    holder.tvUserRank.setText(MessageFormat.format("{0}-", holder.getAdapterPosition() + 1));

    if (Memory.userUid(context).equals(userList.get((holder.getAdapterPosition())).getUserUid())) {
        holder.tvPoints.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.pink));
        holder.tvUserName.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.pink));
        holder.highLightView.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.pink));

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to implement the else block as well

```
if (Memory.userUid(context).equals(userList.get((holder.getAdapterPosition())).getUserUid())) {
        holder.tvPoints.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.pink));
        holder.tvUserName.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.pink));
        holder.highLightView.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.pink));

    }else{
            holder.tvPoints.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FaFaFa"));
            holder.tvUserName.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FaFaFa"));
            holder.highLightView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FaFaFa"));
}
```